# maximize profit with n products satisfying certain constraints

Tags: algorithm

I am given a list of n products with associated profits and costs per unit. The aim is to maximize the profits while keeping the total cost below some threshold. For each product either one or zero are produced.

Now suppose we have three products and Suppose we label these products 1,2 and 3. Then all possible combinations of productions can be given as the binary numbers 111,110,101,011,100,010,001 and 000, where a 1 in the i^th position denotes a production of one of product i and similarly for zero. We could then easily check which of these combinations has a production cost under the threshold and has the maximum profit. This algorithm would then be of order O(2^n) because for n products we have to check 2^n binary numbers. We can probably make this a little faster by recognizing that if 100 is above the threshold already we need not check 110 and 111 and some stuff like this but the order will not change because of this. How can I make a smarter algorithm maybe that has a better time complexity. The n can be as large as 100 in which case checking 2^100 numbers is not possible. Thanks in advance

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Answer (score 0):

If your costs are integers that are not too big, you can use the dynamic programming solution for the knapsack problem, which is listed in the link mentioned in David Eisenstat's comment. If your costs are either big integers or fractional, then your best bet is using one of the existing knapsack solvers that e.g. reduce to an integer linear programming problem and then do something like branch and bound in order to solve. At any rate, your problem IS the knapsack problem, with the only slight modification that you don't have to fill the knapsack completely, you can fill it partially as long as you don't overfill it. However this variant is also studied along with the original formulation, and there are solvers for it. Also it is easy to modify the dynamic programming solution to handle this, let me know if it's unclear how and I'll update my answer with an explanation.